# Prevent from listing Amazon s3 bucket content

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have similar issue with Amazon s3 bucket. https://serverfault.com/questions/693815/how-to-stop-s3-from-listing-some-of-the-content

It is working fine when i remove "List" permission, the bucket contents are not visible. But when I upload an item to that bucket via API, again the "List" permission got ticked and anyone can view all the items with the bucket.

This is the PHP code where I upload item to the bucket

$this->s3->putObjectFile($path, $this->bucketName, $fileName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

I wanted to keep un-tick "List" permission even I upload a new item. What should i do ?

Comment: Are you saying that in your testing, the act of uploading a single object with the public-read ACL re-enables the "List" permission to grantee "Everyone" for the entire bucket, under bucket Properties > Permissions in the console, after you have disabled it?

Comment: yes.. any solutions ?

Comment: Well... no.  That should not happen.   I can't duplicate it by storing a public object.  From the REST API docs, however, it does appear that it might be possible to toggle the "List" option for the entire bucket if you had a bug and called `putObjectFile()` with `$path` set to an empty string (or maybe undefined or just `/` depending in the SDK behavior) because  buckets don't have a root object -- the bucket *is* the root object, and setting the acl on the root object *is* setting it on the bucket.

Comment: Im not sure what i'm missing. I got the s3 class from http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/ and I'm using to $this->s3->putObjectFile($path, $this->bucketName, $fileName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ); to upload. Here $path is passing correctly without empty or undefined. Please help me with this

Comment: [Enable S3 logging on the bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html).  Then, do some testing, wait for new logs to appear, and review them.  If you see any `PUT /` or `PUT /?acl` requests logged (no object key, just `/`), that's going to be the problem and you'll need to investigate where they are coming from, since that's what a request to change the bucket ACL should look like in the logs.  Unless there is a serious defect in S3 itself, which seems unlikely, *something* appears to be sending such a request to your bucket, resetting this value.

Comment: I have solved the problem and answered below. Thanks for you help too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using standard libraries (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php). Now it is working perfectly. Seems some problem with http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/